# Switching between PreferenceFragment and android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a BottomNavigationView where I can navigate between fragments. The third fragment is a `PreferenceFragment` while the other two extend `Fragment`. I have a simple switch case for replacing fragments but I get an error that `SettingsFragment cannot be converted to Fragment`.

How can I navigate between these fragments?

```
  BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    toolbar.setTitle("Home");
                    selectedFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    toolbar.setTitle("Dashboard");
                    selectedFragment = DashboardFragment.newInstance();
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_settings:
                    toolbar.setTitle("Settings");
                    selectedFragment = SettingsFragment.newInstance();
                    break;
            }
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, selectedFragment);
            transaction.commit();
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Unless you're using the support preference library, PreferenceFragment extends `android.app.Fragment`, so you need to use the same for your other Fragments.

Comment: @TheWanderer, that helped. If you want to add your comment as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're using the support preference library, PreferenceFragment extends `android.app.Fragment`, so you need to also extend `android.app.Fragment` for your other Fragments.

However, since Fragment and PreferenceFragment have been deprecated in API 28, you might want to just convert to the support Fragment and PreferenceFragmentCompat. Be aware that this will mean any Preference libraries you might be using will probably not work until they've been updated.

Comment: Since `PreferenceFragment` is deprecated (along with all of `android.app.Fragment`, it probably makes more sense to change to `PreferenceFragmentCompat`

Comment: @ianhanniballake only if you're targeting 28. Also, I've noticed that the compat versions seem to be missing a lot of features that the normal ones have. You also lose access to quite a few preference libraries.

Comment: `android.app.Fragment` was only officially deprecated in API 28, true, but none of the bug fixes in Fragments are backported to older versions of Android (nor any of the new features such as support for Architecture Components), so switching to `android.app.Fragment` is always going to a big step backward. As of the 28.0.0 versions of the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` libraries, they also offer more functionality than the framework version.

Comment: @ianhanniballake do they? Maybe I'll give them another shot. But there's still the problem of libraries. Most of them only have normal versions.

Comment: Hopefully the deprecation of the framework versions will help libraries realize they need to switch over. It seems like in this particular case though, there's no `PreferenceFragment` based libraries being used.